# Joining list item with string in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to join an item in a list with a string and evaluate that command, cmd1 returns the incorrect value of 0. cmd2 returns the correct value, I'm doing something wrong trying to join the list item with a string but I don't see it. This is in python 2.7.10.

```
import os
import string
import subprocess
import sys

for ii in range(len(shas)-1):
    cmd1 = 'git diff --numstat %s %s | wc -l' % (shas[ii], shas[ii+1])

    cmd2 = "git diff --numstat 8b694f0 a9aa580 | wc -l"

    output1 = subprocess.check_output(cmd1, shell=True)
    output2 = subprocess.check_output(cmd2, shell=True)
```

Comment: before using `subprocess.check_output` do a `print(cmd1)` and post it here plz.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Are you sure the values in `shas` are correct?

Comment: make sure you use `print(repr(cmd1))` so we can see what non-printable characters might be included.

Comment: Great call! 
How can I remove these special chars?
'git diff --numstat \x1b[33m8b694f0 \x1b[33ma9aa580 | wc -l'

Comment: The original command I was using had color codes. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @iheartcpp: those are *ANSI color codes*. You may want to run your git commands without colour support (add `--no-color` to the command line).